# highmaps click on country and change its background color, Also remove the Series 1 from tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, highmaps

I am testing this highmaps for my appication and I could not find this information, Anybody with a link or answer please

1. After clicking on a country, how to changeits background color to lets say red color,
2. How to remove the extra data from the tooltip, I want to display country name only.
3. How to set some of the countries with one color lets say "#CCCCCC" and disabled counteries with #ffffff.

**Code**

```
plotOptions:{
    series:{
        point:{
           events:{
              click: function(){
                 alert(this.name);
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/farz5vq2/)

Answer (score 1):

***1. After clicking on a country, how to change its background color to lets say red color***

You can change the background-color of the clicked element by setting `this.color` to `'rgb(255,0,0)` . Here an example of `plotOptions`

```
plotOptions:{
    series:{
        point:{
           events:{
              click: function(){
                   alert(this.name);
                   this.color = "rgb(255,0,0)";
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

*Update*

If you want to reset the previous selected element, here is a workaround (haven't found another way yet) Place following code just after the `alert(this.name)` and take a look on the fiddle example for better understanding. (The `oldFill` variable is being initialized just before the map-chart and just temporary stores the original color value of selected element)

```
$(mapChart.find("path")).each(function(){
    if($(this)[0].attributes.fill.value === 'rgb(255,0,0)'){
        $(this)[0].attributes.fill.value = oldFill;
    }
});
oldFill = this.color;
```

***2. How to remove the extra data from the tooltip, I want to display country name only.***

By using following `tooltip` settings, you will get the desired effect.

```
tooltip: {
     headerFormat: '',
     pointFormat: '<strong>{point.name}</strong>',
     footerFormat: ''
}
```

**[Updated JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/uvg9w5pj/1/)**

Comment: after click on one country its making it red, fine. but when i click another country the previous one become red again on hovering it (while i have not selected it)